# ASP.NET Core OData Action With Two Parameters

Tags: asp.net-core, odata

I have this action method available to OData:

```
[HttpPost]
[ODataRoute("({id})/Replace")]
public Blog Replace([FromODataUri] int id, Blog blog)
```

This responds for POST requests on `/odata/Blogs(1)/Replace`.
It is working except for the part that the `blog` parameter is never bound from the POST, that is, it is not null, but has default values for all properties. If I add `[FromBody]` to the parameter, it becomes null. I also tried with a parameter of type `ODataActionParameters`, but it is always null.
This is the relevant part of my model:

```
var replace = builder.EntitySet<Blog>("Blogs").EntityType.Action("Replace");
//replace.Parameter<int>("id").Required();  //this can be added or not, it doesn't matter
replace.EntityParameter<Blog>("blog").Required();
replace.Returns<int>();
```

I read somewhere that an OData action cannot have two parameters, but I am not sure of that. I need the `id` parameter to be present, so I need to find a solution for this.
I am using ASP.NET Core 3.1 and the latest versions of all packages.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution turned out to be simple:

1. The parameter declaration was wrong: the name of the entityset is “blogs”, not “blog”
2. I was posting the JSON for the “Blog” entity, but I had to modify it so as to be included in a parameter “blog”, as this:

   {
       “blog”: {
           “BlogId”: 1,
           << rest of the Blog properties >>
        }
   }

This solved my problem.